# Spring batch : processing list of files

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Spring batch : I have a list of files which I need to process and split into different files and write. I followed the steps mentioned in 
http://incomplete-code.blogspot.com/2013/07/spring-batch-looping-over-multiple-files.html#comment-form

In this we supply the resource property to the FlatFileItemWriter dynamically using 
 .
The first step works fine. However, from the next iteration onwards, instead of taking the new value of "input.file", it keeps using the same file (used in first iteration). Can anybody suggest if I can have a writer in each iteration which can take a new dynamic value of the file ?

Comment: You have to post your code and any error messages it generates.

Comment: first you have to post your work and error details to resolve by other fellow developers.you can do this by using org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader to read from multiple files.

Comment: Actually code is same as in the posted link above. In this code the following is being done :

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue:

Here is a proper description of the problem :

Actually code is similar to the one in the posted link above. 
Then only difference is that I am passing the "input.file" to FlatFileOutputWriter
instead of FlatFileItemWriter.

In this code the following is being done :

1. We pass the job parameter "input.files" as a comma seperated list of file names.
2. In the FileDecision class we retrieve the "input.files" parameter, split it 
   into a list of string and iterate over it. In each iteration, we put a new parameter
   "input.file" in jobExecutionContext.
3. In the spring bean declaration file (xml file), we pass the value of this 
   "input.file" (in jobExecutionContext) to a FlatFileItemWriter (as the value of 
   resource property).
4. Then we pass this FlatFileItemReader to a job step (multipleFileProcess.step1)
   which is being iterated over. We expect the in each iteration, we set a new value
   for  "input.file" (without 's' at the end of file), and we will be able to write
   the content to new output file.

   However, instead of writing in separate output 
   files, it was writing the contents of all the iteration to a single output
   file (the output file which was set to the FlatFileItemWriter in the first iteration)

   The solution I implemented:

   1. Created a CustomItemWriter and injected it into job step (multipleFileProcess.step1)
      which is being iterated over.
   2. Injected the MultiResourceItemWriter to the CustomItemWriter.
   3. Injected the FlatFileItemWrited to MultiResourceItemWriter with resource value="".
   4. In the CustomItemWriter @BeforeStep method, 
      a. created a new Resource with file value retrieved from "input.file" (in jobExecutionContext).
      b. set this new Resource to the MultiResourceItemWriter instance variable.

Now, I am able to write to separate output file in each iteration.
I will post the sample code also after the weekend.

Thanks